# How to create a distribution function in R?

Tags: r, function, statistics, distribution

Given the following function:

```
f(x) = (1/2*pi)(1/(1+x^2/4))
```

How do I identify it's distribution and write this distribution function in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is your function right now (hopefully you know how to write an R function; if not, check [writing your own function](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions)):

```
f <- function (x) (pi / 2) * (1 / (1 + 0.25 * x ^ 2))
```

`f` is defined on `(-Inf, Inf)` so integration on this range gives an indefinite integral. Fortunately, it approaches to `Inf` at the speed of `x ^ (-2)`, so the integral is well defined, and can be computed:

```
C <- integrate(f, -Inf, Inf)
# 9.869604 with absolute error < 1e-09

C <- C$value  ## extract integral value
# [1] 9.869604
```

Then you want to normalize `f`, as we know that a probability density should integrate to 1:

```
f <- function (x) (pi / 2) * (1 / (1 + 0.25 * x ^ 2)) / C
```

You can draw its density by:

```
curve(f, from = -10, to = 10)
```

[image: density]

Comment: Thank you, wonderful response again! Now that I have the probably distribution function I was wondering how to create a random sample of say n = 1000 using this new distribution function?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Ok yes I see that is the integration.

Comment: Yes but I understand now and I solved it, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Now that I have the probably distribution function I was wondering how to create a random sample of say `n = 1000` using this new distribution function?

**An off-topic question, but OK to answer without your making a new thread. Useful as it turns out subtle.**

[image]

Compare

```
set.seed(0); range(simf(1000, 1e-2))
#[1] -56.37246  63.21080
set.seed(0); range(simf(1000, 1e-3))
#[1] -275.3465  595.3771
set.seed(0); range(simf(1000, 1e-4))
#[1] -450.0979 3758.2528
set.seed(0); range(simf(1000, 1e-5))
#[1] -480.5991 8017.3802
```

So I think `e = 1e-2` is reasonable. We could draw samples, make a (scaled) histogram and overlay density curve:

```
set.seed(0); x <- simf(1000)
hist(x, prob = TRUE, breaks = 50, ylim = c(0, 0.16))
curve(f, add = TRUE, col = 2, lwd = 2, n = 201)
```

[image]